# On Button click view is not removing from the parentView?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inflater

I am inflating a view from the parent view .it is inflating fine.the view is adding as many time i wanted ,but when i want to delete a particular view ,it's not removing that view.
while that button is working on toasts.but not on removing view.

here is mine main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".Activity.Reminders">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/remindertoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reminders"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addreminder"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"

    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="230dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/addreminder1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="123dp"

    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alarmclock"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView68"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="126dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="126dp"
    android:text="@string/no_reminders_added_yet" />
```

And here is mine activity which i am inflating:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reminder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reminder" />

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/custom_mesaage"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:targetApi="o" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/everyday" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/day" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/month" />


        </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listofmode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listofmode2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteimage"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:background="@drawable/delete"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deletetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/delete" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downimage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:src="@drawable/downn"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/upimage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/upp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i want to added view to be removed from the parent but its not.i have added a toast to the button click which it is showing .

here is the code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminderaddition, null);

  deleteme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                layout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is a textview", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                layout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is a button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
```

i am using this [tutorial](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android/):

Comment: what is layout in this line  - layout.removeView(

Comment: post whole activity's code for better understanding

Comment: LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout); @NehaK

Comment: It's not clear which of those `setOnClickListener()` calls you're using, but the `View v` parameter is the `View` that's being clicked. Assuming that's the `<Button>` with ID `deleteimage`, `v.getParent()` is going to return the `<LinearLayout>` that is the direct parent of that `<Button>`. However, that `<LinearLayout>` is not a direct child of `mainlayout`, so nothing happens. You would need to go up another level – i.e., `v.getParent().getParent()` – but this isn't really a great way to be doing this.

Comment: @MikeM. both the setonclicklistner are supposed to delete the child view  from the parent view

Comment: Well, you've only got one normally-clickable `View` in that layout with `delete` in the ID – the aforementioned `<Button>` – so I'm not sure what `deleteme` or `delete` are in the Java code. You should provide a [mcve] with questions like this.

Comment: @MikeM.I am using a linear layout as an container here and have many views like text-views, edit-texts and switches inside that container.Here deleteme is referring to a text-view while delete is an image-view .while clicking on the both i am getting the toast response but unable to remove the view.

Comment: There is no `Toast` in `deleteme`'s `OnClickListener`. Please be specific with your problem descriptions. Which `TextView`? Which `ImageView`?

Comment: @MikeM. check now i changed the view from image to button.

Comment: The `View` type doesn't matter. I've already given you my suggestion. If that doesn't work, then I would suggest that you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: which view you want to remove? write its id here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `layout.removeView((View) v.getParent());`

With    `layout.removeView((View) v.getParent().getParent());`

as you have 2 level hierarchy in your layout file so you have to get root linear layout which is again parent of your internal linear layout.

Comment: it is removing the button on which i am clicking.

Answer (score 0):

To remove view use following code :

```
layout.removeView(findViewById(VIEW_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_REMOVE));
```